# Docker Compose JVM parameters

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose

I wrote a java application that takes an environment variable that takes an argument to set a key for a JWT token salt key. Is there a way for me to pass the command variables in Docker Compose?

```
java -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /user-profile-api.jar --key=blah
```

And to run the docker image you just

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 docker_image --key=blah
```

Comment: So you _already_ can run the image like that? You can just pass the `--key=blah` bit as the `command` attribute for the service in the compose file.

Comment: That worked! Thanks! Mind adding it as an answer and I will add select it?

Comment: Glad it worked, done :)

Comment: @JoelHolmes, is the java command above located in the entrypoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already are able to run your docker container using:

`docker run -p 8080:8080 docker_image --key=blah`

Then you just need to override the `command` attribute for your `service` in the compose file to --key=blah. So:

```
services:
  app:
    command: --key=blah
...
```

Comment: Please note: passing system arguments only works if you have _exec_ form entrypoint (e.g.: `["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]`). Details are described [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint)

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to put your java command in a shell script (say, `bootstrap.sh`), and set that as your command to run in docker compose. And then in `bootstrap.sh` inject the key via an environment variable which is in your `docker-compose.yml`.

E.g.

bootstrap.sh

```
java -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /user-profile-api.jar --key=$SALT_KEY
```

docker-compose.yml

```
build: .
environment:
    - SALT_KEY=blah
command: /opt/app/bootstrap.sh
```

Obviously you'd need to package up `bootstrap.sh` into your container for this to work.

Comment: This looks like it would work, but is there another way to be more flexible?

Comment: maybe, but flexible is a vague term, can you say exactly what flexibility you'd like to have?